# Google calendar script title update

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, title, series

Can anyone help me to get the following script to work for calendarseries.   It works perfectly for all single calendar events.  But it there is a recurring event it only changes the colour and does not update the title.

I want the following to happen

User creates an event and they invite the shared calendar.  This then updates the event title with the users name.

The even title only needs to be updated on the shared calendar

```
function Update_Business() {

  var mycal = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com";
  var mainCal = "xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com";
  var First = new Date();
  First.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  var Last = new Date();
  Last.setDate(First.getDate() + 30);

  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
  var events = cal.getEvents(First, Last, { search: '-At' });
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var ev = events[i];
    Logger.log(ev.getTitle())

    var title = ev.getEventSeries().getTitle();

    var eventId = events[i]
    var title = events[i].getEventSeries().getTitle();
    var creator = events[i].getEventSeries().getCreators();
    var contact = ContactsApp.getContact(creator);
    var CreatorName = contact.getNickname()

    events[i].getEventSeries().setTitle(CreatorName + " at     " + title).setColor(11);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this code but I think it might help.

```
function Update_Business() 
{
  var mycal = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com";
  var mainCal = "xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com";
  var min=60 * 1000;
  var hr=60 * min;
  var day=24 * hr;
  var wk=7 * day;
  var First = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0));
  var Last = new Date(start.valueOf() + (30 * day));

  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
  var events = cal.getEvents(First, Last, { search: '-At' });
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) 
  {
    var ev = events[i];
    Logger.log(ev.getTitle())
    var title,eventID,creator,contact,creatorname;
    if(ev.isRecurringEvent())
    {
      title = ev.getEventSeries().getTitle();
      eventID=ev.getEventSeries().getId();
      creator=ev.getEventSeries().getCreators();
      contact = ContactsApp.getContact(creator);
      creatorname = contact.getNickname();
      ev.getEventSeries().setTitle(creatorname + " at     " + title).setColor(11);
    }
    else
    {
      title=ev.getTitle();  
      eventID=ev.getId();
      creator=ev.getCreators();
      contact = ContactsApp.getContact(creator);
      creatorname = contact.getNickname();
      ev.setTitle(creatorname + " at     " + title).setColor(11);
    } 
  }
}
```